# Spring MockMVC, Spring security and Mockito

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, mocking

I'd like to test a `Spring Boot` Rest controller, which is secured using `Spring security`, and use mocks inside it. I have tried with Mockito, but I think any mocking tool should do the trick.

To enable Spring security in my tests, I first did as follow:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Main.class)
@TestPropertySource(value="classpath:application-test.properties")
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTest{

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(wac)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void doTheTest(){
        mockMvc.perform(post("/user/register")
            .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())
            .content(someContent()));
    }
}
```

Until there, it works well.

After this step, I wished to add mocks to test my secured controller in isolation.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Main.class)
@TestPropertySource(value="classpath:application-test.properties")
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTest{

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private Myservice serviceInjectedInController;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(wac)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void doTheTest(){
        mockMvc.perform(post("/user/register")
            .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())
            .content(someContent()));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the mocked service is not injected in the controller, as there is nothing relating the MockMVC and the Mocks, so the mocks are not injected in the controller.

So I tried changing the configuration of the MockMVC, as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Main.class)
@TestPropertySource(value="classpath:application-test.properties")
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTest{

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private Myservice serviceInjectedInController;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;


    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standAloneSetup(myController)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void doTheTest(){
        mockMvc.perform(post("/user/register")
            .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())
            .content(someContent()));
    }
}
```

But in this case, I have another issue. Spring security is complaining about the configuration:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: springSecurityFilterChain cannot be null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.
```

I have no other idea to make security and mocking. Any idea? Or should I do another way?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using Spring Security 4+ version?

Comment: I al using Spring-boot 1.2.7.RELEASE and I have overridden default Spring security to use 4.0.2

Comment: @Remi Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @hvgotcodes Not yet, but I have not given up to succeed one day. I'll do it later if I have time to find an idea.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default the integration looks for a bean with the name of "springSecurityFilterChain". In the example that was provided, a standalone setup is being used which means `MockMvc` will not be aware of the `WebApplicationContext` provided within the test and thus not be able to look up the "springSecurityFilterChain" bean.

The easiest way to resolve this is to use something like this:

```
    MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            // replace standaloneSetup with line below
            .webAppContextSetup(wac)
            .alwaysDo(print())
            .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
            .build();
```

If you really want to use a standaloneSetup (doesn't really make sense since you already have a WebApplicationContext), you can explicitly provide the springSecurityFilterChain using:

```
@Autowired
FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

@Before
public void startMocks(){
    controller = wac.getBean(RecipesController.class);

    MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(controller)
            .alwaysDo(print())
            .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
            .build();

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong, but using `standaloneSetup` is the only way to have a sufficent control on the controller to be able to inject Mocks inside. Or is there another way?

Comment: You can create a test configuration that provides mocks for your services. Then exclude the configuration that has the actual services. Alternatively, you can use both configurations and mark `@Primary` on the mock version of the services. To setup expectations and verify you can `@Autowire` the mock services in.

Comment: In my case springSecurityFilterChain is still null...What else do I need to provide here?