# Spring @WithMockUser and request.IsUserInRole()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito

I am using:

```
request.IsUserInRole("ADMIN")
```

in one of my controllers to determine the response to the request. I tried to mock the request in my test like:

```
@Mock
private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
```

and to use Springs annotation `@WithMockUser`:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(roles={"USER, ADMIN"})
public void getAccountsTest() throws Exception {...}
```

Both didn't work.

Question 1: How can I mock `request.IsUserInRole("ADMIN")` in a JUnit test?

Question 2: What influence does `@WithMockUser` have on the request and `request.IsUserInRole("ADMIN")`?

Thanks and best regards

---- edit ----

"Didn't work" means I have a test method:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "user", roles={"USER"})
public void getAccountsReturnForbiddenTest() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/accounts/"))
        .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
}
```

which should return 403, not allowed because of the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<AccountResource>> getAccounts(...){...}
```

But the request returns 200, OK.

And I am using Spring Boot 1.4.1.

---- edit 2 ----

My JUnit Test-class:

```
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration
public class AccountControllerTestDoc extends AbstractControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private AccountController accountController;

    @Mock
    private AccountService accountService;

    private String uriBase = ""; 

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // Initialize Mockito annotated components
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        // Prepare the Spring MVC Mock components for standalone testing
        setup(accountController);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "user", roles={"USER"})
    public void getAccountsReturnForbiddenTest() throws Exception {
        String uri = uriBase + "/accounts";
        mockMvc.perform(get(uri))
            .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

}
```

with AbstractControllerTest:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class AbstractControllerTest extends AbstractTest  {

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    protected void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    protected void setup(BaseController controller) {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller))
                .build();
    }
}
```

and AbstractTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public abstract class AbstractTest {

    protected Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

}
```

---- solution ----

`MockMvc` `standaloneSetup` isn't aware of the web application context and therefore not aware of the security filter chain. One has to setup `MockMvc` with the web application context and the security filter chain to be able to test security aspects.

Here is my now working solution, I edited the AbstractControllerTest:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class AbstractControllerTest extends AbstractTest  {

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    protected void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(wac)
            .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain)
            .build();
    }

    protected void setup(BaseController controller) {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Didn't work" means...

Comment: Excuse me, "Didn't work" means I am running a get request on a secured method with no admin role and the return status is not the expected 403(not authorized) but 200(ok).

Comment: Please show how you're setting up your `mockMvc`.

Comment: I had a similar case and this worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/32777599/4614788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `springSecurityFilterChain` while creating the `MockMvc`

```
protected MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
protected WebApplicationContext wac;

@Autowired
protected Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

protected void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
   .webAppContextSetup(wac)
   .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain)
   .build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Little bit more background regarding standalone setup for MockMvc from http://stackoverflow.com/a/34316901/3139759 I added the solution in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username="xx", roles= {"TIMESHEET"})
public void createNew() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    
    assertTrue(Constants.isUserInRole("ROLE_TIMESHEET"), "user not in correct role");
```

Where Constants.isUserInRole is defined as

```
public static Boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()).map(x->x.getAuthorities()).get()
            .stream().anyMatch(x->x.getAuthority().equals(role));
}
```

Then use this isUserInRole rather than request.isUserInRole.